# Import error in linux but success on windows

Tags: python, linux, windows

```
import os
os.chdir('../../')
print os.getcwd()
import sys
import unittest
from chatbot_run.chatbot_conf import chatbot_conf_dict

/home/mengyuguang/yige
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_time_entity.py", line 21, in <module>
    from chatbot_run.chatbot_conf import chatbot_conf_dict
ImportError: No module named chatbot_run.chatbot_conf
```

chatbot_run is a project that I wrote.
I am doing this import of the fifth line which works fine on Windows.
The python file is in yige/test/ner folder and I run the file in this folder, too.
It printed yige and chatbot_run is in yige, too.
This is really strange. What's the difference in linux that causes this.

Comment: Insert your error into the question

Comment: Thank you, can you figure out what's happening?

Comment: it seems that you have not installed the package on your linux running  machine

Comment: `ImportError: No module named chatbot_run.chatbot_conf` That's your problem - it's failing to import the configuration file on your windows machine.. is it available for import?

Comment: @eamirgh this is a project that I wrote.

Comment: Is the directory that the file `chatbot_run` is located in, on your python path?

Comment: @AK47 Yeah, it 's good for import. My problem is on linux. Not located in  my python path. If I import it in yige, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your project path to `sys.path` instead of using `os.chdir`.

```
sys.path.append("../..")
from chatbot_run.chatbot_conf import chatbot_conf_dict
```

Comment: It worked, but why it worked on windows using os.chdir?

Comment: Most IDEs in Windows automatically adds your project path to `sys.path` for you. I suspect that this is the case.

Comment: Yeah,you were right, I printted the path and saw that pycharm added my project path to sys.path automatically.